# Is there is any API for retrieving call log in to the other app usig android?

Tags: php, android, html

I am creating a Child Monitoring APP in android. I want to **retrieve** the **call logs** from one app to the other app. What are the APIs available for this? or What is the recommended method to achieve this?

Comment: What does "retrieve the call logs from one app to the other app" mean?

Comment: There is a Module in our Final Year Project (Child Monitoring App), To track call log history and messages History from the Child's Mobile Phone to another app in Parent's Mobile.To monitor the consumption of mobile phone.

Comment: You mean to get the call log and messages on one device and to another device? If so please make the question more clear.

Comment: and....welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Do https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible using android.

you need to use an [aidl](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) file which works as client and server app. you need to write your own logic for getting a log and then using an aidl file you can share it across the app